# Is there existing DSP libraries to process Audio in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, signal-processing

I've looked at popforge, but it looks or feels like there's some missing implementation or lack of documentation on how to use it.

Do you know of any existing libraries to process raw PCM data (a ByteArray of values essentially) inside of:

- A Parametric EQ;
- LP / HP / HS / LS EQ;
- Delay Unit (Stereo, Ping Pong, etc.);
- Reverb Unit;
- Phaser;
- Flanger;
- Compressor;
- etc...

Ideally some kind of ported **FMOD** library to AS3 would be cool. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make it yourself Sound.extract() but be warned it is not 100% real-time

Comment: True, Sound.extract can be useful for pulling the raw-data from the Sound. But how to process it remains a mystery! Any good Mathematical resources / links would be great.

Comment: Here is something that might help you learn whats going on. http://www.flashcomponents.net/tutorials/dynamic_sound_generator_in_actionscript_3.0.html